# How to recovery data throw the log file in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, recovery, logfile

Who can help me?I am using the sql server 2008,and i have the backup file with full recovery before my database was broken,now the data file can't be append,how can i recovery the data throw the log file and the full recovery before?